# What tool do I use to make a part smooth

Tags: tools

I have what is on image 1 (the black colors), and i want it to be like the image 2 (orange color legs)

[image: 2]

I know that there a tool that can do it but i can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the subsurf mod! https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html

Extra characters to fill answer quota.

Comment: But how do i transform the octagon into a circle

Comment: Simply add the modifier.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much!!